# GCP Vision AI Label Detection Definitions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Does anyone know if Google Cloud provide the definitions of labels extracted from the pictures using GCP Vision AI tool?

Answer (score 0):

GCP Vision AI does not provide with the definitions of the labels extracted from the pictures, and Google does not provide with an API for Google Dictionary.

However, there are some [public repositories](https://github.com/meetDeveloper/googleDictionaryAPI) that may fulfill your purposes.

Also, if you could elaborate on your use case I may help you further.